# I am getting error parsing JSON. Why do I get that error?

Tags: json, format, erlang

I have some old code and I forget the right json format.

```
try
    {L} =  ejson:decode(JsonStr),
    ?INFO("json======>~w", [L]),
    {_, {L1}} = lists:keyfind(<<"total">>, 1, L),
    {_, Id} = lists:keyfind(<<"id">>, 1, L1),
    {_, Name} = lists:keyfind(<<"name">>, 1, L1),
    {_, IconId} = lists:keyfind(<<"icon_id">>, 1, L1),
    {_, Title= lists:keyfind(<<"Title">>, 1, L1),

     {_, L2} = lists:keyfind(<<"child">>, 1, L),..
    Fun =
    fun({L3}) ->
            {_, Id1} = lists:keyfind(<<"id">>, 1, L3),
            {_, Bid} = lists:keyfind(<<"bid">>, 1, L3),
            {_, TotalId1} = lists:keyfind(<<"total_id">>, 1, L3),
           
         ...
            
    end,...
```

So this is my json format:

```
 'total'=>
    [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 1,
    'icon_id' => 503,
    ],
    'child'=>
    [
    'id' => 1,
    'group' => 0,
    'total_id' => 20,
  ...]
```

But I am getting error parsing JSON. Why do I get that error?

Comment: Maybe `{"total": {"id":1, "name":1, "icon_id":503}, "child": {"id":1, "group":0, "total_id":20}, …}`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual JSON:

```
'total'=>
    [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 1,
    'icon_id' => 503,
    ],
    'child'=>
    [
    'id' => 1,
    'group' => 0,
    'total_id' => 20,
  ...]
```

then it's malformed. You should check out the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). The long and the short of it is, JSON objects start and end with curly braces `{}`, keys are double-quoted `""` and the separator between key and value is a colon `:`.

```
  {
    "total" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : 1,
      "icon_id" : 503
    },
    "child" :
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "group" : 0,
      "total_id" : 20
    } ...
  }
```

If you're trying to write ejson, that can be expressed as a map:

```
#{
  <<"total">> => #{
    <<"id">> => 1,
    <<"name">> => 1,
    <<"icon_id">> => 503
  },
  <<"child">> => #{
    <<"id">> => 1,
    <<"group">> => 0,
    <<"total_id">> => 20
   }..
}
```

or a tuple/list thing in erlang terms. There's a really helpful representation in the [jiffy README](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy#data-format) that I've copied here:

```
Erlang                          JSON            Erlang
==========================================================================
null                       -> null           -> null
true                       -> true           -> true
false                      -> false          -> false
"hi"                       -> [104, 105]     -> [104, 105]
<<"hi">>                   -> "hi"           -> <<"hi">>
hi                         -> "hi"           -> <<"hi">>
1                          -> 1              -> 1
1.25                       -> 1.25           -> 1.25
[]                         -> []             -> []
[true, 1.0]                -> [true, 1.0]    -> [true, 1.0]
{[]}                       -> {}             -> {[]}
{[{foo, bar}]}             -> {"foo": "bar"} -> {[{<<"foo">>, <<"bar">>}]}
{[{<<"foo">>, <<"bar">>}]} -> {"foo": "bar"} -> {[{<<"foo">>, <<"bar">>}]}
#{<<"foo">> => <<"bar">>}  -> {"foo": "bar"} -> #{<<"foo">> => <<"bar">>}
```

It looks like your parser is expecting parsing out the ejson into an set of erlang terms like this:

```
{[{<<"foo">>, <<"bar">>}]} -> {"foo": "bar"} -> {[{<<"foo">>, <<"bar">>}]}
```

If your decoder has any ability to return a map, I would suggest you send that option along as they are MUCH MUCH easier to work with. If your decoder can't do that, then I would suggest you try and switch to using [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy).

Comment: oh forgot to say i use this code array/json format over php and sending it to the erlang server.  When you use this code in php i will get the same json format like you                     $array=[  'total'=>
        [ 'id' => 1,
        'name' => 1,
        'titel' => 503,],
        
        'child'=>
        [ 'tea' => 1,
        'name' => 1,
        'age' => 503,]
        ]
        ;
print_r(array(json_encode($array)));                                                                                                          not working. So i will rewrite my erl file and test it